# Pegar valor do AUTO_INCREMENT de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quero pegar o último registro cadastrado em uma tabela do banco de dados, ou seja, o valor do `AUTO_INCREMENT` da tabela,  tentei usando:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as max FROM people
```

Ele funciona, porém se eu não tiver nenhum registro na tabela ele retornará `NULL`, o que pode ser errado, pois nem sempre que retornar `NULL` a tabela é nova, por exemplo:

> Crio 5 registro na tabela, e logo após isso eu apago os 5, a minha
>   *query* vai retornar o `NULL` enquanto deveria retornar o 5 (que foi o último a ser registrado, independentemente se foi apagado ou não).

Li sobre o [lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php) do *PDO*, porém nos exemplos, sempre é preciso executar uma *query* de `INSERT` antes do `lastInsertId()`.

Qual a melhor maneira de obter o valor atual do `AUTO_INCREMENT` de uma tabela a qualquer momento?

**PS:.** Quando digo 'a qualquer momento' quero dizer que não seja preciso inserir, atualizar ou deletar um registro antes de poder pegar.

Comment: dê uma olhada nisso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761403/how-to-get-the-next-auto-increment-id-in-mysql

Comment: Então você não quer pegar o id do último registro, e sim o valor atual da sua chave certo?

Comment: Isso aí é um treco que quase sempre dá problema. Uma vez obtido o valor e guardado numa variável, como é que você faz pra evitar que ele mude externamente e não colida?

Comment: @Bacco eu também estava pensando nisso, creio que não terá problema, pois o periodo de tempo que essa variável é usada é extremamente curto, uso quando insiro um dado no banco de dados, dai pelo o último para armazenar como id da classe.

Comment: @Fleuquer Lima sim, logo também ele sera igual os últimos registrado, mesmo que o último registrado por ventura tenta sido apagado.

Comment: Existe o certo e o errado, o mais ou menos certo não existe: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_corrida

Comment: @bigown não conhecia essa 'Condição de Corrida', li o artigo e pesquisei mais sobre o assunto, analisei o código usado e creio eu que no caso não virá a ocorrer tal falha, pois não há processos simultâneos no caso, logo, 'acho' que não ocorrerá. Obrigado por citar, um conhecimento a mais :)

Comment: Tem algum mecanismo que garanta que não haverá processos simultâneos? Principalmente em PHP não costumo ver isto.

Comment: Fiz apenas esperando o resultado de um, enquanto não tiver esse resultado ele não partirá para o outro processo. Sempre faço apenas assim, não sei se há outra maneira para evitar isso.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Faça uma consulta no [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html) ele guarda as informações sobre os seus banco de dados(metadados), o campo a ser retornado é o `AUTO_INCREMENT`, é necessário informar a tabela e database.

O código abaixa retorna o **próximo valor** do auto-increment, caso o último registro inserido tenha sido o de id 200, a consulta retornará 201.

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'tabela' AND table_schema = 'database' ;
```

**Baseado em:** [How to get the next auto-increment id in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12500309/1342547)

Comment: **Obs:** só adicionar um -1 para pegar o último elemento cadastrado.

Comment: Não é só adicionar um -1 pra pegar o ultimo elemento cadastrado, essa afirmação não procede. Você pode estar com o `auto_increment` em 200 e não ter um 199 na tabela. Tanto pelo fato de o registro 199 ter sido deletado, quanto uma tabela nova criada com autoincrement no 1000, por exemplo.

Comment: @Bacco vou corrigir depois, faz sentido o comentário numa sequencia quebrada :P a lógica quebra tbm.

Comment: @rray acho que o buraco é até mais embaixo, vide comment que eu deixei na pergunta :)

Comment: PS: no caso, tirando o -1, acho que fica certo

Comment: No caso o -1 serviria, pois o objetivo não era pegar o indicador do último registro registrado ainda existente, e sim do último independentemente se ele foi excluído ou não. Mas cada caso é um caso, é válido salientar a questão do -1 para os visitantes.

Answer (score 0):

use assim:

```
select coalesce( max( id ), 0) + 1 from tabela
```

Comment: Testei aqui, retornou 1, quando deveria ter retornado 8.